# how to change text color in category view in magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, category

I am trying to change text color in magento 2 for product names and nested names in category view.

Can someone point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If You need to change **Product Name color In Product details** Page:

Add below **css Code** to our custom Theme:

```
 body{

    color:red !important
  }
```

Next If you want change **Product Name Color In Category Page**:

Add below **css Code** to our custom Theme:

```
  .product-item-name > a, .product.name a > a {
        color: red !important;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

**Update:**

You need to create one custom them like **luma , blank**. then add this above css code to our custom theme.

Folow this link to create custom theme:

1. https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-magento-2-theme.html
2. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html
3. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-theme-magento-2-part-1/
4. http://blog.belvg.com/creating-and-managing-themes-in-magento-2-0.html

Comment: Thanx, what do you mean our custom theme

Comment: I update my answer